# Have string returned from one method print out in another method, in Java?

Tags: java, string, recursion, methods

I have the following code, which I put together:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringReverser {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("Please enter some text to reverse.");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = scan.nextLine();
    reverse(userInput);
  }

  public static String reverse(String userInput) {
    int i = 0;
    while (userInput.length() <= 0) {
      return userInput;
    }
    String reversed = reverse(userInput.substring(1)) + userInput.charAt(0);
    return reversed;
  }

  public static void displayData(String reversed) {
    System.out.println(reversed);
  }
}
```

I want the returned reversed string from the reverse method to be printed in the `displayData` method.

How do I get it to print from there?

Comment: call reverse method from display data . displayData(reverse(userInput))

Comment: just call  `displayData(reversed);` from where you want to printl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be some thing as below

```
                public class StringReverser {
              public static void main(String args[]) {
                System.out.println("Please enter some text to reverse.");
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                String userInput = scan.nextLine();
                displayData(reverse(userInput));
              }

              public static String reverse(String userInput) {
                int i = 0;
                while (userInput.length() <= 0) {
                  return userInput;
                }
                String reversed = reverse(userInput.substring(1)) + userInput.charAt(0);
                return reversed;
              }

              public static void displayData(String reversed) {
                System.out.println(reversed);
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
displayData(reverse(userInput));
```

Answer (score 1):

call reverse method from display data .

```
displayData(reverse(userInput))
```

or you can save the returned value in string variable like

```
String reverseString = reverse(userInput);
 displayData(reverseString )
```